# What remains uncovered when covering the rationals with sets with measure 0 in the limit?

Tags: measure-theory

We can order the rational numbers between 0 and 1 as follows:

> 1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 2/3, 1/4...

Now we can prove that the rationals have measure 0 [as follows](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219231531/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51860.html): For each e, construct an interval of length e/4 around the first point, e/8 around the second and so on halving each time. As this is a geometric sequence, the sum is $<e$. Since we can do this for arbitrarily small e, the set has measure 0. However the set is also dense.

Can we explicitly name a number that won't be included in these covering sets once e is less than a particular value? If not, can we produce another dense, measure 0 set which can be shown not to include a particular number.

Comment: @quasi: I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @quasi: Yes, but it is less than 1 for sensible e meaning that there are points not included. And they won't be included for any covering with an even smaller e

Comment: @quasi OP is saying that the rationals have measure zero because they can be covered by measure $e$ sets for any $e$, not that the covers have measure zero.

Comment: Yes, it seems I misunderstood.

Comment: Order your rationals as $q_1,q_2,\dots$ and consider the covering $\bigsqcup_{n \ge 0} (q_n-\varepsilon/2^n, q_n+\varepsilon/2^n) \setminus \{\sqrt{2}\}$.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151384

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The golden ratio is more than $1/(3q^2)$ from every fraction $p/q$ so make sure that every interval around $p/q$ is narrower then that.

Comment: How do you prove that?