# Riemann integrable and continuous almost everywhere.

Tags: integration

I want a proof for this theorem:

> Let $f$ be a function on $[a,b]$. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $f$ is bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: I think you mean Riemann.

Comment: See Munkres - Analysis on manifolds for example.

Comment: I put a note here coz I've added it to my favorite. By definition, any Riemann integrable function is bounded. Improper integral are considered as limit of Riemann integrable functions. So  it will be more appropriate to correct the problem as following: Let f be a function on [a,b]. Then f is Riemann integrable if and only if f is bounded **everywhere** and continuous almost everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the Lebesgue criterion for Riemann integrability. You can Google it or see a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151060/conditions-for-integrability) and the wiki [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) for proof.