# Does continuity always imply integrability?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

In terms of Riemann integrability: If we are taking into consideration Riemann integrals on a closed interval, then any continuous function is integrable.

In terms of improper integrals: continuity does not imply integrability.

Comment: The answers below are correct but I want to add something, given $f$ bounded on a compact interval $I$ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $I$ *if and only if* it is continuous *almost everywhere*.

Comment: @holo useful! Here's a link to a discussion elsewhere on this site, though it just has pointers to other things.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238139/riemann-integrable-and-continuous-almost-everywhere

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Theorem**: A continuous function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable.

*Proof:*

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.  Any function that is continuous on a [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Definitions) set—such as our $f$ on $[a,b]$—is also [*uniformly* continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) on that set$^\dagger$.  This is to say, given a $\mu > 0$, we are guaranteed a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - y| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \mu$ for *any* $x, y \in [a,b]$.  Consider a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $[a, b]$ into $n$ equal intervals of width $\displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n}$, with $n$ large enough so that $\displaystyle \frac{b-a}{n} < \delta$.  Computing the difference between the upper and lower sums:
\begin{align*}
U(f, \mathcal{P}) - L(f, \mathcal{P}) &= \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \left(x_k - x_{k-1} \right)\Big[\operatorname{sup}\{f(x) | x \in [x_{k-1}, x_k] \} - \operatorname{inf} \{f(x) | x \in [x_{k-1}, x_k] \} \Big] \\
& \leq \left( \frac{b-a}{n} \right) \cdot n \cdot \mu \ = \ (b-a)\mu
\end{align*}
Given an $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $\mu$ small enough so that $\displaystyle \mu < \frac{\varepsilon}{(b-a)}$.  Then $U(f, \mathcal{P}) - L(f, \mathcal{P}) < \varepsilon$, and we conclude $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

---

$^\dagger$ See **[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-mapping-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous)** for further discussion.

Answer (score 10):

It is worthwhile to give another proof for Riemann integrability of functions which are continuous on a closed interval.

The proof below is taken from *Calculus* by Spivak and I must say it is novel enough. It does not make use of uniform continuity bur rather invokes mean value theorem for derivatives.

The central idea is to show that if $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ is continuous on $[a, b] $ then the upper and lower Darboux integrals of $f$ on $[a, b] $ are equal ie $$\overline{\int} _{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx=\underline{\int} _{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$$ Now to establish the above identity Spivak considers the upper Darboux integrals as a function of the upper limit of integration. Thus following Spivak we consider the function $$J(x) =\overline{\int} _{a}^{x} f(t) \, dt$$ and show that $J'(x) =f(x) $ for all $x\in[a, b] $. Similarly we have $j'(x) =f(x) $ for all $x\in[a, b] $ where $$j(x) =\underline{\int} _{a} ^{x} f(t) \, dt$$ The derivative of function $F=J-j$ vanishes everywhere on $[a, b] $ and $F(a) =0$ so that $F$ vanishes on whole of $[a, b] $.

The key point which needs to be established here is the relation $$J'(x) =f(x) =j'(x), \forall x\in[a, b] $$ and the proof is almost the same as that of first fundamental theorem of calculus. The upper Darboux integrals enjoy the same additive property as Riemann integrals and we have $$J(x+h) - J(x) =\overline{\int} _{x} ^{x+h} f(t) \, dt$$ Further given $\epsilon >0$ the continuity of $f$ at $x$ ensures the existence of a $\delta>0$ such that $$f(x) - \epsilon<f(t) <f(x) +\epsilon$$ whenever $t\in(x-\delta, x+\delta) $. If $0<h<\delta$ then the above inequality yields $$h(f(x) - \epsilon) \leq J(x+h) - J(x) \leq h(f(x) +\epsilon) $$ or $$\left|\frac{J(x+h) - J(x)} {h} - f(x) \right|\leq \epsilon$$ The same identity holds even when $-\delta<h<0$ and hence by definition of derivative we have $J'(x) =f(x) $. The proof for $j'(x) =f(x) $ is exactly the same (using lower Darboux integrals).

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=1/x$ is continuous on $[1, \infty)$, but $\int_1^{\infty} f(x) dx = \infty$.

Comment: So does that mean my statements are correct?

Comment: This is not a Riemann integral, though.

Comment: Why the downvote ???? In my example the functin $f$ is continuous on $[1, \infty)$ but not integrable over $[1, \infty)$.

Comment: @Fred This is an [improper Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral). Usually the Riemann integral (in the narrow sense) is only defined on an interval $[a, b]$.

Comment: $[1, \infty)$ is not a closed interval. The questions asks about Riemann integrals on closed intervals, so the counterexample in this answer is not relevant to the question.

Comment: $[1, \infty)$ is closed !

Comment: @Fred No. I think $\infty$ is not considered as a number. The interval you mentioned is not closed at all. It is not bounded above. It starts at $1$ and keeps on going (sorry for non-mathematical language).

Comment: @Fred closed and boundedness are required to prove that a continuous function is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @DarkKnight: in the topoligical sense the intervall $[1, \infty)$ is closed, since the complement $( - \infty,1)$ is open.

Comment: You need the set to be compact (for the uniform continuity) and not only just closed, and in $\mathbb{R}$, from the Heine-Borel theorem, this is equivalent to the set being closed and also bounded, but obviously $[1, +\infty)$ is not bounded as we can always find a bigger upper bound which would lead to a contradiction.