# Help with partitioning an interval for Riemann integral of piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

If $f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      x &-1<x\le0 \\
      x^2 &0<x\le1\\
   \end{cases}
$ then prove $f$ is integrable on $[-1,1]$
I am studying this topic, and my textbook has no example how to partition a piecewise function. I know the formulas for lower sums and upper sums, but I need some help with partitioning and deciding for component intervals, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102844/how-do-i-prove-that-a-function-with-a-finite-number-of-discontinuities-is-rieman) to easily prove your proposition. It is worth thinking about this construction in general, but also how it would be specifically applied to you problem.

Comment: but here  the function is continuous. the page you refered me to is discussing of points of discontinuoity.

Comment: Huh, I didn't even notice that it was continuous (I assumed the different pieces introduced a discontinuity). You should try to prove that every continuous function is integrable.

Comment: Well that is what I had in mind. even choosing a function g on a broader interval to show f is differentable on all [-1,1]. but I believe I am supposed to use upper and lower sums. so there is no way to partition such interval? I ve been googling this for hours and I can not see any similar problem to see how this proof might look like.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825787/does-continuity-always-imply-integrability).

Comment: the behaviour of function here is know on (-1,1], the question is asking wether it is integrable on [-1,1]. am I supposed to consider this at all? thanks

Comment: Integrals are unchanged if you change the function by a point. Just extend the domain to be $[-1,1]$.