# Why does $f$ in $\int f(x)\, dx$ have to be continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, continuity, indefinite-integrals

Let $f:(a\,..b) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $F:[a\,..b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be two real functions. Let $F$ be differentiable on $(a\,..b)$ and continuous on $[a\,..b]$. Let $f$ be continuous on $(a\,..b)$. Then $F$ is called an antiderivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ iff $\forall x \in(a\,..b):F'(x)=f(x)$.

Why, in this definition, does $f$ need to be continuous on $(a\,..b)$? Why isn't $F$ considered an antiderivative of $f$ when $\forall x \in (a\,..b):F'(x)=f(x)$ but $f$ isn't continuous?

Comment: It doesn't have to be continuous.

Comment: Because if $f$ is not continuous at some point $x$, then the derivative of $F$ might not be defined at $x$. Take for example $f(x)$ equal to $1$ on the positive real axis and $0$ otherwise...
However, as duly pointed out by @MathematicsStudent1122, being continuous is not necessary to define the integral (but there *are* some conditions you have to impose).

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud but $F$ is already assumed to be differentiable on the whole interval.

Comment: @mathematician Well then $f$ is automatically continuous, isn't it? (At least, to me differentiable means $C^1$.)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud "but there are some conditions you have to impose" What are these conditions?

Comment: @asdasdfsss See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151060/conditions-for-integrability

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I think it's pretty standard to define "a function that is differentiable on some interval" as "a function that is differentiable at all points on the interval" and nothing more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you can call $F$ an antiderivative of $f$ even when $f$ isn't continuous. That's just a matter of terminology. I'm not sure what the conventions are.

However, note that if $f$ is continuous, it is very easy to prove that the antiderivative $F$ actually exists. You just take $F(x) = \int_a^x f$; the fact that $F'(x) = f(x)$ follows by observing that $(F(x+h)-F(x))/h = (1/h)\int_x^{x+h} f$ which tends to $f(x)$ as $h \to 0$ by continuity of $f$.

Also, note that for $f$ Lebesgue integrable but not necessarily continuous on $[a,b]$, the function $F(x) = \int_a^x f$ obeys $F'(x) = f(x)$ almost everywhere. So the notion of antiderivatives does apply to discontinuous $f$. See Theorem 7.11 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.